How to measure the time it takes to forward a packet from one interface to another?
I want to measure the time it takes between when a packet is forwarded by wg0 (wireguard interface) to eth0. The packet decryption is already performed by the time wg0 consults the OS routing table for the destination Ip (let's say a public ip) which is then forwarded to eth0 but the question that I ask is a generic one.
I want to measure this delay since I'll be adding some processing in the way like some tc rules to figure out how much of an overhead would tc bring when I eventually add a couple of thousand tc rules.
I was told that it would be possible using bpftrace. What would be the bpftrace script to achieve that?
